# How to closing text content with stripe at of end line text every inside element

Tags: javascript, html

I have an problem, i want to automatically closing the end of line in element with stripe when its offsetWidth lower than body width.

For example
[image]

when i change underscore with stripe, its look like this
[image]

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>Testingggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="justify">dasdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="justify">asgjdhgdgagdasda hasdahsdas asldsad asdjasldsadas</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td align="justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
  </tr>
</table>


var td = $("td[align='justify']")
var b_left = $('body').offset().left,
    b_width = $('body').width();

for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
 var q = td[i];
 for (var j = q.offsetWidth; j < b_width; j++) {
   if (q.offsetWidth < b_width) {
      q.textContent += '-'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your intended output from this? to fill the remaining space between the last character and the end of the `td` with hyphens (`-`/stripe)? Can I ask why?

Comment: I have an report format which its output [like this]: https://goo*gl/Zoi8ET i'm using mpdf to genarate it into pdf file

Comment: (shudders) Ok, design criticism's aside, the hyphens then dont need to be selectable? they are just there for the purposes of showing the end of the line?

Comment: Ya, the hyphens just show in the last of line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be something than can be handled with a background image that looks like a hyphen rather than appending text and testing width.

The trick is to use absolutely positioned pseudo elements layered behind a covering text section. We do this by wrapping the content in a `span` element that has the same `background-color` as the page, and leveraging `linear-gradient` to create the "dashes".

**RESULT**

[image]

**CSS**

```
td[align="justify"]{
    position:relative;
}
td[align="justify"]:before,
td[align="justify"]:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:2px; /* handle span not reaching quite to the edge when using text-align:justify */
    right:2px; /* handle span not reaching quite to the edge when using text-align:justify */
    bottom:0px;
}
td[align="justify"]:before{
    /*
    COLOR NOTES:
    black = color of the "dash"
    */
    background-color:black;
}
td[align="justify"]:after{
    /*
    COLOR AND SIZING NOTES:
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) = background-color of page (white)

    First gradient runs left to right and creates the "gaps" in the black
    1px = "gap" of background color, then remainder transparent

    Second gradient runs top to bottom, we want a 1px line in the "middle" of our line-height
    (lineheight / 2) - (1px / 2)
    (18 / 2) - (1 / 2)
    9 - .5 = 8.5
    This creates a 1px high transparent "gap"
    */
    background-image: 
            linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255,1) 1px, rgba(255, 255, 255,0) 1px),
            linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255,1) 8.5px, rgba(255, 255, 255,0) 8.5px, rgba(255, 255, 255,0) 9.5px, rgba(255, 255, 255,1) 9.5px);
    /*
    SIZING NOTES:
    6px = 5px wide dash + 1px wide gap
    18px = text line-height
    */
    background-size:6px 18px, 6px 18px;
    background-repeat:repeat;
}
td[align="justify"] > span{
    background:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Testingggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="justify"><span>dasdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="justify">
            <span>asgjdhgdgagdasda hasdahsdas asldsad asdjasldsadas</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="justify"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="justify"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pzLcu8qg/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. [Check out this codepen for the working code](http://codepen.io/nhuyvan1106/pen/PWJNEV)

```
var td = $("td[align='justify']")
var b_left = $('body').offset().left,
    b_width = $('body').width();

for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
 var q = td[i];
 var width = 0; // The leftover space to fill
 for (var j = q.offsetWidth; j < b_width; j++) {
   if (q.offsetWidth < b_width) {
      width++;
    }
  }
  var bar = document.createElement('span');
  bar.className = 'bar';
  bar.style.width = width + 'px';
  // You could move these next 3 lines to a style sheet under the selector
  // td[align='justify'] .bar if prefer
  bar.style.display = 'inline-block';
  bar.style.height = '1px';
  bar.style.backgroundColor = 'black';

  q.append(bar);
}
```